# How to have folders in the SSMS 2017 project?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2017

I am using **SSMS 2017** and **SQL server 2017**, I have many companies and each company has many databases.

**For example. I have five companies:**

Company1, Company2, Company3, Company4, Company5

**Every company has many databases:**

Employees_DB, Products_DB, Customers_DB (we are talking about 15 database)

Each of the previous databases has many tables.

How can I create a folder for each company, so it has all its own databases?

**To be the result :**

Company1 folder : Employees_DB, Products_DB, Customers_DB

Company2 folder : Employees_DB, Products_DB, Customers_DB

Company3 folder : Employees_DB, Products_DB, Customers_DB

Company4 folder : Employees_DB, Products_DB, Customers_DB

Company5 folder : Employees_DB, Products_DB, Customers_DB

Comment: What do you mean by project? It looks like in this case an illustration would help to understand what exactly you are talking about. Specifically, I would appreciate an illustration showing where you want the folders to be, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can create groups in the server registration view... not sure how that fits with your use of the word ‘project’, so whether it’s suitable for you - you need to decide.

[Create or Edit a Server Group (SQL Server Management Studio)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/register-servers/create-or-edit-a-server-group-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Thank you for your time, this is a good solution when I want to give each company its own server, but I have only one server, and I want to put a folder inside for each company, I want to dedicate many folders in the server with the names of the companies

Comment: There's nothing like this in SSMS, I'm afraid. There's Server Registration as suggested, but that is at the server level. And there's "Solution and Projects" in SSMS, but that is just a "grouping" of sql files. And differentiating logins doesn't really help either since all logins sees all databases (unless you can make the login the owner of the database and DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE). Having categorization/grouping at various level would be a cool feature in SSMS - considering request this at https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server.